# Create a generic JSONPatch object

Tags: java, java-8, jackson

I want to create a DTO for Jackson to serialize my jsonPatch variables into a json patch variable.

I have this attributes to represent the class Person:

```
  @JsonProperty("lastName")
  private String lastName;
  @JsonProperty("firstName")
  private String firstName;
  @JsonProperty("age")
  private int age;
  @JsonProperty("a")
  private A classA;
```

And also the class A has:

```
@JsonProperty("colour")
private String colour;
@JsonProperty("quantity")
private BigDecimal quantity;
```

The DTO that I created was something like this:

```
@JsonProperty("path")
protected String path;
@JsonProperty("op")
protected String operation;
@JsonProperty("value")
protected Object values;
```

The json patch that I receive can have on the values class either a Person or the class A:

Patch for Person:

```
[
 {
  "value":
   {
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "firsName": "John"
  },
"path": /people",
"op": "replace"
 }
]
```

Patch for A:

```
[
 {
  "value":
   {
    "quantity": 12.1,
  },
"path": /A",
"op": "remove"
}
]
```

The value can be either a Person or a class A, as I told you, that's why the value is an Object class.

My problem is that when Jackson serializes the value from Person, it serializes to a Map, and when the value is from object A, it serializes to a double, which will lead to casting the values, which could be very dangerous.

Is there any way to tell Jackson that the values are from a Person object or from an A object, so it can serialize without any cast?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a common class with all the properties and add `JsonIgnoreProperties` to the class so that Jackson will ignore unknown properties while deserializing

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Common {

     @JsonProperty("colour")
     private String colour;

     @JsonProperty("quantity")
     private BigDecimal quantity;

     @JsonProperty("lastName")
     private String lastName;

     @JsonProperty("firstName")
     private String firstName;

     @JsonProperty("age")
     private int age;

     @JsonProperty("a")
     private A classA;

 }
```

And then after deserializing the JSON to `Common` object just do `null` check to identify deserialized JSON is `Person` or `A` class

```
if(common.getFirstName()!=null && common.getLastName()!=null)
     // Person class

if(common.getQuantity()!=null)
    // A class
```